# Trying to figure out some C code by going through Suckless's slstatus

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to understand the battery remaining function of slstatus so that I can implement  it through the shell.

```
timeleft = (double)charge_now / (double)current_now;
h = timeleft;
m = (timeleft - (double)h) * 60;
```

I don't understand why for calculating the minutes remaining they subtract timeleft with h.
wouldn't that just give you zero?

here is the complete function:

```
const char *
battery_remaining(const char *bat)
{
    uintmax_t charge_now, current_now, m, h;
    double timeleft;
    char path[PATH_MAX], state[12];

    if (esnprintf(path, sizeof(path),
                  "/sys/class/power_supply/%s/status", bat) < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (pscanf(path, "%12s", state) != 1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!pick(bat, "/sys/class/power_supply/%s/charge_now",
              "/sys/class/power_supply/%s/energy_now", path,
              sizeof(path)) ||
        pscanf(path, "%ju", &charge_now) < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!strcmp(state, "Discharging")) {
        if (!pick(bat, "/sys/class/power_supply/%s/current_now",
                  "/sys/class/power_supply/%s/power_now", path,
                  sizeof(path)) ||
            pscanf(path, "%ju", &current_now) < 0) {
            return NULL;
        }

        if (current_now == 0) {
            return NULL;
        }

        timeleft = (double)charge_now / (double)current_now;
        h = timeleft;
        m = (timeleft - (double)h) * 60;

        return bprintf("%juh %jum", h, m);
    }

    return "";
}
```

https://github.com/drkhsh/slstatus/blob/master/components/battery.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uintmax_t charge_now, current_now, m, h;
double timeleft;

timeleft = (double)charge_now / (double)current_now;
h = timeleft;
m = (timeleft - (double)h) * 60;
```

`timeleft`is a variable of type double. So his value is something like `7.34`.

When assigning `timeleft` to h which is an integer variable, the fractional part is discarded, so in my example, `h` value is 7.

When `m` is computed, note the cast of `h` to a double. So `(timeleft - (double)h)` gives 0.34. 0.34 multiplied by 60 gives 20.4 which when assigned to the integer variable `m` is truncated to 20.

Probably the compiler issue warning about the truncation that occurs when a double is assigned to an integer.

Comment: oh wow I get it now. Not sure how to implement this in a shell script but I at least understand the code.. Thanks!